# using collections in SOQL INCLUDES

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to achieve the following using a set/list collection:

```
List<AccountContactRelation> accountContactRelationsList = [
            SELECT ContactId, AccountId, Roles
            FROM AccountContactRelation
            WHERE Roles INCLUDES ('finance', 'marketing')
];
```

I tried the following; however, it does not work

```
List<String> roles = new List<String>{
        'finance',
        'marketing'
};

String rolesAsString = String.join(roles, ',');
    
List<AccountContactRelation> accountContactRelationsList = [
     SELECT ContactId, AccountId, Roles
     FROM AccountContactRelation
     WHERE Roles INCLUDES :roles
];
```

A workaround would be to use the `Database.query()`; however, I prefer to use normal queries since the compiler can detect syntax errors. Do you know how to include the items of a collection in the keyword `INCLUDES`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm):

> Bind expressions can't be used with other clauses, such as INCLUDES.

You will have to use dynamic SOQL and generate the required SOQL syntax, something like:

```
List<String> roles = new List<String> {
        'finance',
        'marketing'
};

String rolesAsString = '(\'' + String.join(roles, '\', \'') + '\')';
    
List<AccountContactRelation> accountContactRelationsList = Database.query(
    'SELECT ContactId, AccountId, Roles ' +
    'FROM AccountContactRelation ' +
    'WHERE Roles INCLUDES ' + rolesAsString);
```

Note, however, that you will need to ensure that each of the "roles" values are appropriately encoded (before being incorporated into the rolesAsString value) to prevent SOQL injection issues using String.escapeSingleQuotes.

Comment: Minor correction, the set doesn't work with String.join method, it needs list. I see this is problem in OP's code though. :)

Comment: Yeah, fixed. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had been stuck in this for a while, here's a pointer for people who come finding for this in future:

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Products__c FROM Case where Products__c INCLUDES (\'' + srch + '\')';
List<Case> cseList =DataBase.query(queryString);
```

Where srch is your dynamic string.